# What's the technical definition of this CSS behavior?

Tags: css, html, browser

Go to the following Foundation CSS framework documentation url:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/navigation.php

In the section named **Nav Bar** you will see an example for horizontal navigation bar. Now try to gradually minimize the browser's window, when the window is minimized enough (to be like mobile devices resolution) you will notice that horizontal navigation bar is turned into vertical navigation bar. I need to know the technical definition for this behavior occurred to the menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [responsive web design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design); which is design that adapts based on the user agent's viewport.

Twitter's [bootstrap framework](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) for example, has responsive design built-in.

Answer (score 1):

I've reproduced that effect using `width: auto; float:left` for each menu item, and on resize event I'm checking if all the items are aligned at their top. If the items are not aligned, I'm modifying to `width:100%`

here is an example of what I got: [www.gabitzish.com](http://www.gabitzish.com) (see menu)